# Recursing Through Multiple Text Files with References

Tags: file, loops, powershell, search

I have hundreds of text files in a folder which can often reference each other, and go serveral levels deep.  Not sure if I am explaining this well, so I will explain with an example.

Let's say folder "A" contains 500 .txt files.  The first one could be called A.txt and somewhere in there it mentions B.txt, which in turn mentions C.txt and so on.  I believe the number of levels down is no more than 10.

Now, I want to find a certain text strings which relate to A.txt by programmitically going through that file, then if it sees references to other .txt files go through them as well and so on.  The resulting output would be something like A_out.txt which contains everything it found based on a regex.

I started out with this using Powershell but am now a little stuck:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\TEST\" -Filter *.txt
$regex = ‘PCB.*;’

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $infile = $files[$i].FullName
    $outfile = $files[$i].BaseName + "_out.txt" 
    select-string $infile  -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $outfile
}
```

It goes through every .txt file and outputs everything that matches the PCB.*; expression to its corresponding _out.txt file.

I have absolutely no idea how to now expand this to include references to the other files.  I'm not even sure if this is possible in PowerShell or whether I need to use another language to achieve what I want.

I could get some office monkey's to do all this manually but if this is relatively simple to code then it would save us a lot of time.  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

---

/Edit

Whilst running through this in my head, I thought I could build up an array for every time another one of the files is mentioned, and then repeat the process for those as well.  However, back to my original problem, I have no idea how I would go about this.

/Edit 2:

Sorry, had been away for a few days and am only just picking this up.  I have been using what I've learnt from this question and a few others to come up with the following:

```
function Get-FileReference
{
    Param($FileName, $OutputFileName='')

    if ($OutputFileName -eq '')
    {
        Get-FileReference $FileName ($FileName -replace '.xml$', '_out.xml')
    }
    else
    {
        Select-String $FileName -Pattern 'BusinessObject.[^"rns][w.]*' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | Add-Content $OutputFileName

        Set-Location C:\TEST
        $References = (Select-String -Pattern '(?<=resid=")d+' -AllMatches -path $FileName | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value })

        Write "SC References: $References" | Out-File OUTPUT.txt -Append

        foreach ($Ref in $References)
        {
            $count
            Write "$count" | Out-File OUTPUT.txt -Append
            $count++
            Write "SC Reference: $Ref" | Out-File OUTPUT.txt -Append

            $xml = [xml](Get-Content 'C:\TEST\package.xml')
            $res = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//res[@id = $Ref]/child::resver[last()]')
            $resource = $res.id + ".xml"

            Write "File to Check $resource" | Out-File OUTPUT.txt -Append

            Get-FileReference $resource $OutputFileName
        }
    }
}

$files = gci "C:\TEST" *.xml
ForEach ($file in $files) {
    Get-FileReference $file.FullName
}
```

Following my original question, I realised that this was a little bit more extensive than I originally thought and therefore had to tinker.

These are the noteable points:

1. All the parent files are .xml and code that matches on
       "BusinessObject" etc works as expected.
2. The references to other
       files are not simply .txt but require a pattern match of
       **'(?<=resid=")d+'**.
3. This pattern match needs to be cross referenced with another file **package.xml** and based on the value
       it returns, the file it next needs to look into is **[newname].xml**
4. As before, those child .xml files could reference some of the
       other .xml files

The code I have pasted above seems to be getting stuck in endless loops (hence why I have debugging in there at the moment) and it is not liking the use of **$Ref** in:

```
$res = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//res[@id = $Ref]/child::resver[last()]')
```

That results in the following error:

```
Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."
```

Since there could be hundreds of files it dies when it gets over 1000+.

Comment: If you can tell the "office monkeys" how to do the task then you can tell PowerShell; But it's almost impossible to guess text processing commands that will match your text without seeing example text. "*Outputs everything that matches the `PCB.*;` expression*" - but what is the relevance of `PCB.*;` ? Are those the filenames? What kind of text is in the `.*` bit? What would you expect as output for multiple references to B in A? What about loops `A.txt -> B.txt -> A.txt` ? What kind of output would you expect at all for `A.txt -> B.txt -> C.txt` - one out file, three files, something else?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, the PCB.*; is a regex for anything that starts with PCB and ends in ; which is what I want to return for every data file.  There are no loops, so A.txt > B.txt > C.txt and so on.  C.txt would never go back to B.txt etc.  In A.txt there would be references to B.txt, D.txt, and then in B.txt and D.txt there would be more strings starting with PCB and ending with ; which I want to output to the file called A_out.txt.  B.txt and D.txt could have references to E.txt and F.txt so I want to check those files too for PCB and output them to A_out.txt.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, if there are multiple references to B.txt in A.txt then it can either ignore them or it can just repeat the process and I will run a clean up on A_out.txt afterwards to remove any duplicates.

Comment: I understand what the regex is, I don't understand what the string `PCB` has to do with your question; given a line containing `PCB.*;` where is the file reference in that line? How do you get the filename out of that line? Or is that the filename if you strip the `;`?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, apologies if I sounded condecending. PCB*; is just the data I want out.  For example, the text starting with PCB could be "PCB.34567.Hello.ABCG.6667776;"  References to other files will be in the format "B.txt" etc.  So once everything starting with PCB and ending with ; has been written to A_out.txt, it should look for other file references (ie. *.txt in A.txt) and then do the same on those, and continue doing so until it finds no more file references in the last file.  Then repeat the entire process for B.txt etc.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, still a bit stuck here... any chance you can take a quick look please?

Comment: It wouldn't like the use of `$ref` in a single quoted string, PowerShell only substitutes variables in double quoted strings. As for the rest, I don't speak XSLT and I don't have hundreds or thousands of appropriately linked files to test with - but how *certain* are you that the files don't reference each other in a way that loops it back to a file it's already seen and it just gets stuck following a chain of files round in a circle forever?

Comment: I've tried using single and double quotes but its still not accepting it as a variable.  With regards to the references, I know for sure they do not loop back round.  I'm testing this initially with a handful of files and that too goes on for ages and then dies.

Comment: The debugging I've got on shows that the $Ref in each loop is the same (the first entry in $References), even though the array $References has multiple entries.

Comment: Managed to fix part of it... had to define $References as = @(Select-String blah blah)

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function which tries to do what you want.

```
function Get-FileReference
{
    Param($FileName, $OutputFileName='')

    if ($OutputFileName -eq '')
    {
        Get-FileReference $FileName ($FileName -replace '\.txt$', '_out.txt')
    } 
    else 
    {
        Select-String -Pattern 'PCB.*;' -Path $FileName -AllMatches | Add-Content $OutputFileName

        $References = (Select-String -Pattern '^.*\.txt' -AllMatches -path $FileName).Matches.Value
        foreach ($Ref in $References)
        {
            Get-FileReference $Ref $OutputFileName
        }        

    }
}

$files = gci *.txt
ForEach ($file in $files) { Get-FileReference $file.FullName }
```

It takes two parameters - a filename and an output filename. If called without an output filename, it assumes it's at the top of a new recursion tree and generates an output filename to append to.

If called with an output filename (i.e. by itself) it searches for PCB patterns, appends to the output, then calls itself on any file references, with the same output filename.

Assuming that file references are lines on their own with no spaces `xyz.txt`.

Comment: Cheers Dude!  Since my last comment I was tinkering with my own code and got it working up to 3 levels deep... albeit I did it all manually with nested for loops and it was really messy lol.  Just about to commute to the office so will go through your code (a learning exercise for me) and test it out.  Will update you shortly.  Regardless of whether it is successful or not, your help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: It is giving me the following error: 
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\TEST\script.ps1:11 char:46
+         Select-String -Pattern 'PCB.*;' -Path <<<<  $FileName -AllMatches | Add-Content $OutputFileName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Comment: @hshah I can't imagine how it's ending up being called with `$FileName` being null... have you changed the file reference regex or something, maybe?

Comment: I hadn't changed anything, but following the error I started looking at what I had originally and your version.  I changed the first line in the else { } to:  Select-String $FileName -Pattern 'PCB.*;' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | Add-Content $OutputFileName    and the GCI to   $files = gci "C:\TEST\" *.txt  The main part of the code is working as expected now, but I haven't had the chance to properly test the file reference bit.  One of the initial tests was giving me a call depth overflow error so I will try and debug that first before bothering you.

Comment: I've updated my original question with some issues I am facing.  When you have a spare few minutes, would you mind having a look please?

Comment: any thoughts mate?